# How to use routerLinks with ng2-materialize tabs?

Tags: angular, tabs, materialize, angular-routing

I'm using a package for my angular 4 app called [ng2-materialize](https://sherweb.github.io/ng2-materialize/tab) because the materialize css version doesn't work as well with a few components.

I was wondering how I would get my app to work using routerlinks within the tabs. `mz-tab-item` accepts a `href` property but that causes a page refresh. This is what I've got:

```
<mz-tab>
  <mz-tab-item [active]="'true'" [label]="'Tab 1'">Tab 1</mz-tab-item>
  <mz-tab-item [label]="'Tab 2'">Tab 2</mz-tab-item>
  <mz-tab-item [label]="'Tab 3'">Tab 3</mz-tab-item>
</mz-tab>
```

I understand that I can just include my components within the `mz-tab-item` tags but the problem with that is that the route doesn't change. I wanted to have a parent component which contains tabs and then a `router-outlet` which changes according to which tab the user has chosen. I've got this to work using another similar package called [angular2-materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize) but I really preferred the documentation on the one I'm currently using. I was thinking of maybe solving my routing issue by using  `this.location.go()` or is that just bad practice. Does anyone know of any possible 'good' solutions to this? I'm trying to do this without using css.